# How do I get a list of Countries, States and Cities from this JSON?

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON that contains the names of Countries, their states and cities of those states. Here is the [json](https://github.com/sagarshirbhate/Country-State-City-Database/blob/master/Contries.json).

I am able to get all the countries but I can't figure out how to get the states based on the selected country and then cities based on the selected state.

Here is how I got the countries.`enter code here`

First to load the file from assets:

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("Contries.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

Then to load the countries into an ArrayList.

```
public void loadCountries(String parent, String child, ArrayList<String> listValue)
{
    try {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray(parent);;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> m_li;

      //  listValue = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);

            listValue.add(jo_inside.getString(child));
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Then this line finally:

```
loadCountries("Countries", "CountryName", countries);
```

After I have selected a country, I want to load its states. maybe something like this:

```
loadCountries("Pakistan", "StateName", states);
```

and then:

```
loadCountries("Islamabad Capital Territory", "CityName", cities);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working with JSON can be error-prone. Why don't we model objects around your data and we can do something a little more clearer.

Overview.

1. Lets' Model your objects
2. Let's Deserialize your raw json into "Objects"
3. Then we can "query" our modelled objects!

### Step 1 - Modelling.

Note I'm not including constructors, getters, setters and any other boiler plate.

```
public class Country {
   private List<State> states;
   private String name;

   public Optional<State> getStateByName(String name) {
      return States.stream().filter(state -> state.getName().equals(name)).findFirst();
   }
}
public class State {
   private List<String> cities;
   private String name;

   public Optional<String> getCityByName(String name) {
      return cities.stream().filter(city -> city.equals(name)).findFirst();
   } 
}

public class CountryDataProvider  {
    private List<Country> countries;

    public CountryDataProvider(String rawData) {
      // parse your json to create a List of object Country (tip: Use something like Jackson or Gson to do this for you). 
      // Ref to part 2
    }
    public Optional<Country> getCountryByName(String name) {
       return countries.stream().filter(country -> country.getName().equals(name)).findFirst();
    }
}
```

## Step 2 - Deserialize.

This is a broad topic and To be honest there is a lot of libraries that will do it better and they are really easy to add to your project. Here are a few:

1. Jackson https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson
2. GSON https://github.com/google/gson <- My pick.

## Step 3 - Query

From here you can do what ever you want

```
countryData = new CountryDataProvider(data);
Optional<List<String>> countriesInPunjab = countryData.getCountryByName("Pakistan")
    .map(country -> country.getStateByName("Punjab")
    .map(state -> state.getCities()); // would give you all the cities in Punjab, Pakistan.
```

The code I have given in my example does use functional and Optional interfaces (in Java 8). Let me know if you want them rewritten in a less functional way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, not very CPU friendly but it works:

First use this method to get a list of countries:

```
 public void loadCountries(String parent, String child, ArrayList<String> listValue)
{
    try {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray(parent);
       // m_jArry;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> m_li;

      //  listValue = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);

            listValue.add(jo_inside.getString(child));
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Call this method like this:

```
loadCountries("Countries", "CountryName", countries);
```

Then use the following method to load the States and Cities.

```
private void getCitiesByState(String countryName, String stateName)
{
    try {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray countriesArray = json.getJSONArray("Countries");

        for(int i = 0; i < countriesArray.length(); i++)

        {
            JSONObject countryJSON = countriesArray.getJSONObject(i);

            if(countryJSON.getString("CountryName").equals(countryName))
            {
                JSONArray statesArray = countryJSON.getJSONArray("States");

                states.clear();

                for(int j = 0; j < statesArray.length(); j++)
                {
                    JSONObject statesJSON = statesArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    states.add(statesJSON.getString("StateName"));

                    if(statesJSON.getString("StateName").equals(stateName))
                    {

                        JSONArray citiesarray = statesJSON.getJSONArray("Cities");
                        cities.clear();


                        for(int k = 0; k < citiesarray.length(); k++)
                        {
                         cities.add(citiesarray.getString(k));
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```